# how to make my html part of the page look differently when I login as a user from a different table in database

Tags: php, html, mysql, css

I have two tables In my database
Admin and agent . I want my viewprofile to look different when I login with user agent from user admin . Like and if statement

If(user logins in as agent from agent table) it should make header color or profile pic be this

..else  if(user logins in as admin from admin  table) it should make the header color or profile pic or body background be like that

Comment: You can use user_group column in user table and then redirect the html page on check of condition.

Comment: If you have same content and you need different look, You can switch style sheets based on the user who logged in.

Include agent.css OR user.css based on the user type.

Comment: Good idea  PHP Geek

Comment: whats the code for switching CSS if a user from agent table in database logs in  or if a user from admin table logs in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is better you can show two views based on the `SESSION` VALUES that you get.

(Eg.) For Example after the successful login you can store the session for the admin as `<?php $_SESSION['role']='admin'; $_SESSION['logins']==true; ?>` and for the agent you can store SESSION like as follows. `<?php $_SESSION['role']='agent'; $_SESSION['logins']==true; ?>`.

For example if you are redirecting the user to the `dashboard.php` page.

In that page you can check the condition like this.

**Dashboard.php**

Note that if you using `SESSION` in the login page you need to restart the SESSION in the pages that you create orelse the session will not work.

```
<?php 

session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['role']=='' || $_SESSION['logins']==false))
{
 header('location: index.php'); // This will redirect to the login page if the Session is not set.
}

if($_SESSION['role']=='admin')
{
// You can display here whatever the contents that you want.
// you can change the color of the CSS inside this. You can write the CSS code or PHP code over this place
}
else
{
// This place you can write the ode for the AGENT.
//Or do whatever manipulations that you need for the Agent to perform.
}
?>
```

Your login.php page to look like this.

**login.php**

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['login']))
{
    // Admin 
    $sql="SELECT * FROM TABLENAME WHERE `username`='' AND `pass`=''";
    After executing this if you get count of the executed query.
    if($count==1)
    {
     session_start();
     You can store the SESSION VARIABLES HERE AND REDIRECT THE PAGE
     $_SESSION['role']='admin';
     $_SESSION['logins']==true;

    }
    else
    {
       // Agent
       $sql="SELECT * FROM TABLENAME WHERE `username`='' AND `pass`=''";
       After executing this if you get count of the executed query.
       if($count==1)
       {
           session_start();
           Here you can store the SESSION FOR THE AGENT DETAILS.
           $_SESSION['role']='agent';
           $_SESSION['logins']==true;
       }
       else
       {
          echo 'Invalid Username and Password';
       }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: @Abbas Ogaji. If you find any hindrance in implementing my code you shall let me know and am glad to help you.

Comment: Can I make an if statement like; if ( the variable $user (in which $user = $_SESSION['user_login']) is from TABLE `admin` DATABASE `progect4`) it should perform a specific task @Naresh Kumar.P

Comment: @AbbasOgaji. I have added the model of how the `login.php` to look like. Have this in model and make a try. you shall do it.